# Kth maximum sum of a contiguous subarray of +ve integers in O(nlogS)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-search

I was reading [this](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/4018/ksubsum-editorial) editorial and got confused with this statement:

> If the array elements are all non-negative, we can use binary search to find the answer in O(n log S) time, where S is the maximum sum of a subarray."

Can anyone explain the above statement.

Comment: Good question. The statement is far from obvious. Apparently the solution is supposed to be doing a binary over the answer. However I am still trying to think of a way to count the bigger sums than a given value X in linear time.

Answer (score 7):

Assume that we have an array `sum`, which at index `ith` store the sum of all element from 0 to `ith`, so, if all element are non-negative, so

```
 sum[0] <= sum[1] <= sum[2] ... <= sum[i] ... <= sum[n - 1]
```

We notice that, the sum of a sub array `(i, j)` of array `A` is `sum[j] - sum[i - 1]`

So, Given a number X, we can easily calculate the rank of this number from all sum of sub array of A as follow:

```
int rank = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    int index = minimum index which sum[i] - sum[index] >= X;
    //As sum[0] <= sum[1] <=... , we can use binary search to find index
    rank += index;
}
```

Finally, to find which number is the `Kth` number, we can use binary search in range `O to S` and use the above algorithm to calculate the rank, with S is the maximum sum of a subarray.

```
int start = 0;
int end = S;
while(start <= end){
   int mid = (start + end) >> 1;
   int rank = calRank(mid , sum)
   if(rank < mid)
      end = mid - 1;
   else if(rank > mid)
      start = mid + 1;
   else
      break;
}
```

So, time complexity is O(nlogS log n).

Comment: Great answer but, Isn't the complexity of this solution O(nlognlogS)...?

Comment: @GauravArora May be, you can use a "2-pointer" technique for reducing the time complexity to an amortized $O(1)$, which makes the time complexity $O(nlogS)$?

Answer (score 3):

None of the existing answers are correct, so here is a correct approach.

First of all as @PhamTrung pointed out, we can in `O(n)` generate the cumulative sums of the array, and by subtracting two cumulative sums we can calculate the cumulative sum of any contiguous subarray in `O(1)`.  At that point our answer is bounded between `0` and the sum `S` of everything.

Next, we know how many contiguous subarrays there are.  Just choose the endpoints, there are `n*(n-1)/2)` such pairs.

The heart of the problem is that given `X`, we need to in `O(n)`, count how many pairs are less than, `m`.  To do that we use a pair of pointers, `i` and `j`.  We run them up in parallel, keeping the sum from `i` to `j` below `X` but keeping them as far apart as possible given that.  And then we keep adding how many pairs there were between them that would also be below `X`.  In pseudocode that looks like this:

```
count_below = 0
i = 0
j = -1
while i < n:
    while j+1 < n or sum(from i to j+1) < X:
        count_below += 1 # Add the (i, j+1) interval
        j += 1
    if j+1 == n:
        count_below += (n-i-1) * (n-i-2) / 2 # Add all pairs with larger i
        i = n
    else:
        while X <= sum(from i+1 to j+1):
            i += 1
            count_below += j - i # Add a block of (i, ?) pairs
```

I can't swear that I got the indexing right, but that's the idea.  The tricky bit is that every time we advance `j` we only add one, but every time we advance `i` we include every `(i, mid)` with `i < mid <= j`.

And now we do binary search on the value.

```
lower = 0
upper = S
while lower < upper:
   mid = floor((upper + lower)/2)
   if count below mid < count_intervals - k:
       lower = mid+1
   else:
       upper = mid
```

Assuming that the sums are integers, this will find the correct answer in `O(log(S))` searches.  Each of which is `O(n)`. For a total time of `O(n log(S))`.

Note that if we're clever about the binary searching and keep track of both the count and the closest two sums, we can improve the time to `O(n log(min(n, S)))` by dropping `upper` to the max sum `<= mid` and raising `lower` to the next higher sum.  Drop the `floor` and that approach also will work with floating point numbers to produce an answer in `O(n log(n))`.  (With `S` being effectively infinite.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done in `O(Klogn)`. `sum[i]` is defined as a prefix sum of the given array up to index `i`. It can sometimes be faster than the previous solution.

1. Construct a max queue `Q` containing pairs of indices `(i, j)`. The order is `(a, b) < (c, d)` iff `sum[b] - sum[a - 1] < sum[d] - sum[d - 1] else if b - a < d - c else if b < d`.
2. Insert the following pairs into `Q`: `(0, 0), (0, 1) ... (0, N - 1)`
3. Iterate `K - 1` times and in every iteration pop the top element `e = (i, j)` off the `Q` and if `i < j` then insert `(i + 1, j)`.
4. Your element is on the top of the queue.