# K-th Largest Sum Contiguous Subarray

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-search, sub-array

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com) question but could not understand this part of its editorial:

**If the array elements are all non-negative, we can use binary search to find the answer in O(n log S) time, where S is the maximum sum of a subarray.**

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032787/kth-maximum-sum-of-a-contiguous-subarray-of-ve-integers-in-onlogs) similar post but could not understand the approach. It would be really helpful if someone could explain how to do this question in O(n logS) in case of non-negative integer array

Comment: This is a duplicate question, but none of the existing answers are correct.  Therefore I'll answer it correctly there, and recommend closing this one.  But thanks for drawing my attention to a fun problem!

Comment: Thank u! But i looked at your answer. I got the part where you are using 2 pointers. But could u explain the binary search part again. I couldn't understand what we are searching for and what to return after binary search.. I am asking here because i don't have enough reputation to comment there

Comment: @Ribash We are searching for the value of the subset sum such that the `k`'th has that sum.  What that means is that all but at least `k` of the subsets have sums at that sum or below, and less than `k` subsets have a sum greater.  At all points `lower` is a lower bound, `upper` is an upper bound, and we play a game of 20 questions to find at what value they meet.

Comment: @btilly Okay, Just to be sure that i got it right, We are trying to find which sum in the subarray sums has (Total - k) elements before it in the sorted representation of subarray sums array. As soon as we find that, we return. Is that right ?

Comment: Before and including it.  Yes.  With less than that before it.  This means that the k'th sum is there.